# Export HBase Data to sqlserver and hdfs

Tags: sql-server, hbase

How to export hbase data to ms sql server? And how to export hbase data to a flat file on hdfs?

Answer (score 0):

If I wanted to put pieces of my HBase table in the HDFS or in a relational database I would scan the table to the local file system. for example:

```
echo " scan 'my_table', {COLUMN => 'col_fam_1', TIMERANGE => [1418565600000, 1418572800000], VERSIONS => 30}" | hbase shell > my_table.col_fam_1.txt
```

(you can look at https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/Shell for more options).
once it's in the local file system you can put it in the HDFS with `hadoop fs -put` or process it to create insert statements for your RDBMS and bulk insert it.